# Strange instantiation in a class

Tags: c++

I am looking over some open source code and they listed some strange instance in a class defined as:

`Obj *&obj;`

I had no idea that was possible! What does that mean or even do? The pointer and reference symbols should counteract in my opinion. But maybe it does something special I do not know about?

Looking in the code, they use it as if the instance was a pointer. ie: `obj->method()`. So then why did they include the `&`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is reference to a pointer. Think in this way:

```
A *pa = new A(); //pa is pointer to A

A * & rpa = pa; //rpa is reference to pa

rpa = nullptr;  //it modifies pa as well

if ( pa == nullptr )
{
     std::cout << "pa is nullptr" << std::endl;
}
```

It will print *"pa is nullptr"* on the console.

If you find `A * &` difficult to read, then you can use typedef as:

```
typedef A* PA;

PA & rpa = pa; //same as before
```

Comment: Thank you. I almost got lost in the mentality that it was just the same as a regular pointer. But this case is rather interesting that (from your example) `rpa` can change `pa`. Never imagined that I could have used in in conjunction with a pointer before. Only used references as function args and `return *this`.

Answer (score 2):

The code like you wrote it won't compile, since it declares a reference to a pointer, but the reference is uninitialized. For example, the following code won't compile:

```
string *&s;
```

(unless it's a member in a class), but this will:

```
string *p;
string *&s = p;
```

Another possibility, is that this is just a typo and they meant to write `Obj *obj;` ;)

Comment: That will compile if it is a member of a class!

Comment: @Nawaz True, I haven't thought of that. Edited to reflect comment.

Answer (score 1):

That's a reference to a pointer. After all, a pointer is also a value. You might use it to reassign a pointer held by the caller. To illustrate:

```
bool allocate(t_object*& p) {
  assert(0 == p);
  p = new t_object;
  ...
}
```

Then:

```
t_object* obj(0);
if (!allocate(obj)) {...}
// obj now points to something
```

Some people find it easier to manage/read that its most direct alternative (`bool allocate(t_object** p)`).

As to why a reference to a pointer was chosen in the program -- there's not enough context, but you can ask yourself if the program would be *better* if the member were declared `t_object** const`?

Answer (score 0):

It's a reference to a pointer. A pointer is a data-type, why shouldn't you be allowed to have references to one?

It means the same thing as any other type reference - it's an alias for a pointer.

Comment: Can you actually declare a reference variable w/o assigning a lvalue or rvalue in (c++11)

Comment: Reference always refers to something. There's no such thing as a "null reference".

Comment: @minus: Yes, you can *declare* a reference without initialising it. It needs to be initialised from a valid object when it's created.